# Module framework other than OSGI, EJB(not really) and Impala

Tags: java

I am interested in looking at module frameworks that support many of the goals of OSGI such as:

- a module can be restart/replaced
- a module can hide classes and control what is exported.

Impala:

Seems quite interesting but seems tightly coupled to the Spring Framework which amonst other things means i am sucking in a lot of dependencies which become globally shared ( could be wrong about the last point).

Are there any other frameworks or libraries that offer the above features with minimal dependencies ?

It would be great if any supported the ability to set a security manager for that module so each module has different abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Impala aims to solve some of the goals of OSGi - in particular, the ability to reload application modules, with a strong focus on productivity and testability. It provides a dynamic services environment for application code.

However, it does not offer any class hiding, selective exporting or versioning of third party libraries (the ones that sit in the lib directory of your webapp folder), so the treatment for these is the same as for a standard Java app.

Architecturally, I have made an effort to not couple Impala to Spring directly, but in practice it is (Spring provides the basis for the dependency injection and dynamic proxies which make the system dynamic - in theory this role could be satisfied by another framework such as Google Guice, but in pra).